# Two brachos one mikvah

Tags: halacha, blessing, tevilas-keilim-dipping, shlichus-agency, kavana-intent

If I made a bracha and immersed two vessels, and then someone came over and asked me to immerse their vessel as well, since I did not have their vessel in mind, do I say a new bracha?

Comment: Why ask about *two* specifically?

Comment: If it's anything like shechita, then yes. But I don't know if it's the same. (*though I don't see why it **shouldn't** be the same...*)

Comment: @Shokhet Or if it's anything like food.

Comment: @Ypnypn Also true :)

Comment: @msh210 Presumably to simplify the case since the wording of the _b'racha_ may have had to change if you'd only had one to begin with.

Comment: @WAF so "at least two" is meant?

Comment: @msh210 That is my uninformed assumption. If so, I suspect once again that Ani Yodeya intended to simplify things as much as possible, and not to violate conventional [entailment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downward_entailing).